# CodeIgniter 3 Multi part form data

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem when i do an upload of an image from the multi part form created for a dashboard. All is working good, i found the new image data saved on his table in the database, but i don't found the uploaded images in the uploads dir.

This is the controller:

```
public function dashboard() {

    $this->bc ='Backend';
    $this->id = 1;
    $this->add ='index';
    $local = $this->Login_model->getInfo(); 

    $err ='';
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('upload');

     $check    = $this->input->post('act');
     if( $check == 'local' ){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'city', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('postalcode', 'postal code', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('street', 'street', 'required');  
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('metadescription', 'metadescription', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('metakey', 'metakey', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fadescription', 'fadescription', 'required');

        if( $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE )
        {

        }
        else
        {
            unset($_POST['act']);
            unset($_POST['id']);


            $id = 1;
            $result = $_POST;

            $this->load->model('Login_model','model');
            $in_id = $this->model->updateLocal($result,$id);

            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG");

            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

            if( isset($_FILES['files']['name']) && ( count($_FILES['files']['name']) > 0 ) ){
               for( $i=0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++ ){
                     if($_FILES['files']['name'][$i] !=""){

                         $temp = substr($_FILES['files']['type'][$i], strpos($_FILES['files']['type'][$i], "/") + 1);  
                        $extension = $temp;


                         if ((($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/gif')
                            || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/jpeg')
                            || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/jpg')
                            || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/JPG')
                            || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/pjpeg')
                            || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/x-png')
                            || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$i] == 'image/png'))
                            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
                              if ($_FILES["files"]["error"][$i] > 0) {
                              } else {
                                   $names[$i] = time().$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                                   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $config['upload_path'], $names[$i] );
                                   if($i == 0 ){
                                     $this->model->insertImg($names[$i],$id,1);
                                   }else{
                                     $this->model->insertImg($names[$i],$id,0);
                                   }
                              }
                            } else {

                            }

                     }
               }
            }

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Information updated');

            redirect('backend/dashboard');

        }  

     }


    $out =  $this->load->view('backend/dashboard',array('err'=>$err),true);
    $this->load->view('backend/dashboard',array('content'=>$out,'local' =>$local));

}
```

Comment: replace comma with dot.
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i], $config['upload_path'].$names[$i] );
also check upload folder is writable or not.

Comment: The problem was the comma thank you for your help :)